# Behave step disambiguation/optional step arguments

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm trying to support the following feature scenario:

```
Feature: test
  Scenario: Test optional
      Given attacked by samurai
        And attacked by samurai from behind
```

My steps file is

```
from behave import step

@step('attacked by {opponent}')
def step_attacked_by(context, opponent):
    print(opponent)

@step('attacked by {opponent} from {direction}')
def step_attacked_by(context, opponent, direction):
    print(opponent)
    print(direction)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
behave.step_registry.AmbiguousStep: @step('attacked by {opponent} from {direction}') has already been defined in
  existing step @step('attacked by {opponent}') at steps/test.py:5
```

I then tried to use [optinal arguments](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/step_matcher/use_optional_part.html):

My feature file:

```
Feature: test
  Scenario: Test optional
      Given attacked by a samurai
```

My steps file:

```
import parse

from behave import step, register_type

@parse.with_pattern(r"a\s+")
def parse_word_a(text):
    """Type converter for "a " (followed by one/more spaces)."""
    return text.strip()

register_type(a_=parse_word_a)

@step('attacked by {:a_?}{opponent}')
def step_attacked_by(context, a_, opponent):
    print(a_)
    print(opponent)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
    raise ValueError('format spec %r not recognised' % type)
ValueError: format spec 'a_?' not recognised
```

I don't think I really need an optional argument as long as I can disambiguate the steps in the first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While working with Behave, I noticed that the order in which you define the steps in the steps definition file is important.

Try to define your steps starting with the most specific one first:

```
@step('attacked by {opponent} from {direction}')
def step_attacked_by(context, opponent, direction):
    print(opponent)
    print(direction)

@step('attacked by {opponent}')
def step_attacked_by(context, opponent):
    print(opponent)
```

Running your test.feature doesn't give me the ambiguity error anymore.